# Using two or more SQL query statements in a PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
$query_country = "select abbr,full_name from Country";
$result_country = $db->query($query_country);//this is the first SQL

foreach ( $result_country as $row ){
    echo '<optgroup label="' . $row['full_name'] . '">';
    $abbr = $row['abbr'];

    $query_airport = "select location from Airport where country_abbr = $abbr ";
    $result_airport = $db_other->query($query_airport);//this is the second SQL
    foreach ( $result_airport as $row_prime ){
        echo '<option>'.$row_prime['location'].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

As shown above, the 2nd SQL doesn't work.

I tried to **NEW a PDO variable( $db_other )** in the 'config.php' file, but it still doesn't work.

My question is that how I can use the second SQL in a PHP loop.

The reason why I want to do this is that I need to make a selection table group by the 'Country name'.

Comment: Instead of using multiple queries, try to use `JOINS` instead. That will do you a world of good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to quote your query variable and also use db object `$db` to run query

```
$query_airport = "select location from Airport where country_abbr = '$abbr' ";
$result_airport = $db->query($query_airport);
```

Also check `$abbr` have value so code looks like:-

```
if(!empty($abbr)) {
   $query_airport = "select location from Airport where country_abbr = '$abbr' ";
    $result_airport = $db->query($query_airport);
    foreach ( $result_airport as $row_prime ){
        echo '<option>'.$row_prime['location'].'</option>';
        }
}
```